# Qemu libusb always fails with "Operation not permitted"

Tags: usb, 18.04, permissions, udev, qemu

I'm attempting to pass through USB devices through a qemu KVM and receiving the following error:

> libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/009: Operation not permitted

I've made the following udev (**/etc/udev/rules.d/50-qemuusb.rules**) rule of:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb|usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", MODE="0666"

At first I thought it wasn't working properly, but when I checked, it surely was.  **ls -l** in **/dev/bus/usb/001** reports this:

> lmfaoown@Lmfaoown:/dev/bus/usb/001$ ls -l
>   total 0
>   crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 0 Sep 17 18:33 001
>   crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 1 Sep 17 18:33 002
>   crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 2 Sep 17 18:33 003
>   crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 3 Sep 17 18:33 004
>   crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 4 Sep 17 18:33 005
>   crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 6 Sep 17 18:33 007
>   *crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 8 Sep 17 18:42 009*

You can see that for **009** everyone has R/W, yet it still throws the error.

The program that logs this error is QEMU inside of libvirt (/vars/log/libvirt/qemu).

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong with my permissions?  I've tried chowning the USB to dialout with my user being a member, including libvirt-qemu being a member of it, I've tried seting MODE to 777, all with the same outcome.  I do know the udev has some effect as once I remove the rule QEMU throws this:

> libusb:error [op_open] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/001/003: Permission denied.
>   libusb:error [op_open] libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing the USB device in QEMU, we need to make sure that user running QEMU has the necessary permissions to access the USB device connected to host machine.

I have encounter multiple issue to fix access issue of USB devices in QEMU.

I can see you have udev rules are already taken into consideration. Make sure you have Identify the root hubs and USB devices you want to grant permissions.

User also needs to reload udev rules and trigger udev service by execution the below command:

`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger`

Despite addressing the udev rules usb nodes permission issues and USB device Interface is already claimed by "some driver". Still, the QEMU emulator continued to encounter same issue in properly reading USB device descriptors.

```
qemu-system-x86_64: libusb_release_interface: -4 [NO_DEVICE]
qemu-system-x86_64: libusb_release_interface: -4 [NO_DEVICE]
libusb: error [_open_sysfs_attr] open /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-7/bConfigurationValue failed ret=-1 errno=2
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] File doesn't exist, wait 10 ms and try again
libusb: error [_get_usbfs_fd] libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/042: No such file or directory
[7.616230] xhci_hcd 0000:00:04.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state
```

I discovered a bug within the "qemu-system-x86_64" QEMU binary that is linked to the libusb library. Consequently, I made the decision to compile the QEMU source code with the latest version of the libusb library. Found some useful forum that leads to this decision. [link1](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/problem-passing-through-usb-devices-in-qemu-4175492519/) [link2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/trying-to-wrestle-with-usb-permissions-and-passing-through-devices-qemu-vms-4175672319/)

Please follow the steps mentioned here:

**Build libusb source code and install properly on your ubuntu system**

```
git clone https://github.com/libusb/libusb.git    
git checkout tags/v1.0.22 -b V1.0.22    
./configure --enable-udev --disable-static    
make    
sudo make install
```

**Build Qemu source code**

```
git clone https://github.com/qemu/qemu.git    
git checkout -b stable-6.1 origin/stable-6.1    
./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-libusb --enable-kvm    
make -j16    
sudo make install
```

I am aware that this post is quite old, but I still believe that it could be helpful for others who are struggling with issues related to USB devices and QEMU.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen such issues and they are often due to apparmor denials.
You might report your dmesg here if and which `Apparmor Denies´ it contains to match them.

Others and myself have brought several changes to the apparmor profile upstream so that works by default, but this is only available in later versions.

Below you'll find the most recent section about it and the commits in upstream [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git).

```
2df320609ac # For hostdev access. The actual devices will be added dynamically
2df320609ac /sys/bus/usb/devices/ r,
f88a3d9b0c7 /sys/devices/**/usb[0-9]*/** r,
bf3a4140877 # libusb needs udev data about usb devices (~equal to content of lsusb -v)
bf3a4140877 /run/udev/data/c16[6,7]* r,
bf3a4140877 /run/udev/data/c18[0,8,9]* r,
d4d50bcc799 /run/udev/data/+usb* r,
```

You can add what you need to your `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu` to get that back to your installation.

There are plenty of other changes that affect the dynamic creation of rules for your guest. So if the above isn't enough you might have to try a newer version of libvirt/qemu which means a newer Ubuntu release if that gets you going.

P.S. I file this as an answer, even thou there are chances it isn't your case. But the symptoms you have match exactly, so at least others might find the answer they need here.